# Create comments from a selected range

Tags: vba, excel

I basically want a macro to insert the selection as comments to a selected range. So basically I would require to have two selected ranges? How does this work?

My problem- I have the comments for the cells in a different sheet in rows. And in the second sheet I have column headers for which I need those rows as comments to be inserted.

```
Sub TextIntoComments_GetFromRight()
    Dim cell As Range
    Selection.ClearComments
    For Each cell In Intersect(Selection, ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
      If Trim(cell.Offset(0, 1).Text) <> "" Then
        cell.AddComment cell.Offset(0, 1).Text
        cell.Comment.Visible = False
        cell.Comment.Shape.TextFrame.AutoSize = True
      End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: @Maciej Los well i've only tried how to insert a comment on the same sheet. example a cell to the right as the comment. 

Sub TextIntoComments_GetFromRight()  
Dim cell As Range Selection.ClearComments For Each cell In Intersect(Selection, ActiveSheet.UsedRange) If Trim(cell.Offset(0, 1).Text) <> "" Then cell.AddComment cell.Offset(0, 1).Text cell.Comment.Visible = False cell.Comment.Shape.TextFrame.AutoSize = True End If Next cell End Sub

Comment: To add information to your question, press the "edit" button underneath your post. Do not post code in comments.

Comment: @JAI Were you able to use the answer below?

Answer (score 1):

The following code will accept two range inputs from the user. One for the range that needs comments, and one for the range of comments. These two ranges must be the same size. It will then add the text from the second range as comments to the first range. This will work regardless of which sheet the two ranges are on.

```
Sub TextIntoComments_GetFromRight()
    Dim CommentRange    As Range
    Dim CellComments    As Range
    Dim cell            As Range
    Dim cell2           As Range
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet

    Set CommentRange = Range("A1")
    Set CellComments = Range("A1:A2")
    Do Until CommentRange.Rows.Count = CellComments.Rows.Count And CommentRange.Columns.Count = CellComments.Columns.Count
        Set CommentRange = Application.InputBox("Select the range that needs comments.", Type:=8)
        Set CellComments = Application.InputBox("Select the range of comments to be inserted.", Type:=8)
        If CommentRange.Rows.Count <> CellComments.Rows.Count Or CommentRange.Columns.Count <> CellComments.Columns.Count Then MsgBox "The range sizes do not match. Please select matching range sizes.", vbCritical
    Loop

    Set ws1 = CommentRange.Worksheet
    Set ws2 = CellComments.Worksheet
    CommentRange.ClearComments
    For Each cell In CommentRange
        Set cell2 = ws2.Cells(CellComments.Row + (cell.Row - CommentRange.Row), CellComments.Column + (cell.Column - CommentRange.Column))
        If cell2.Text <> "" Then
            cell.AddComment cell2.Text
            cell.Comment.Visible = False
            cell.Comment.Shape.TextFrame.AutoSize = True
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```